# How to replace or remove text of label manually in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making form, In which name field can contain only alphabets, Space and Backspace. If user tries to enter any other thing it will be handled by exception handler but I am going to display message in form of label that " *Only alphabets, Space and Backspace are allowed.". But when user tries to re-enter proper key at that time program must have to move warning message near text field, but I used label and trying to remove its text or disposing and removing whole object still it stay as it is near that text field.. Please help me to fix it.

Code is here

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Flag As Boolean = False
    Private Sub TxtName_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtName.KeyPress
        Dim Txt As Integer = Asc(e.KeyChar)

        Dim Lbl As New Label
        If (Txt < 65 Or Txt > 90) And (Txt < 97 Or Txt > 122) And Txt <> 8 And Txt <> 32 Then
            e.Handled = True
            Lbl.Text = "*Only Alphabets, Space and" & vbNewLine & "Backspace are allowed."
            Lbl.AutoSize = True
            Lbl.Name = "LblError"
            Lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Lbl.Location = TxtName.Location + New Point(175, 0)
            GrpBxDataInput.Controls.Add(Lbl)
            Flag = True

        ElseIf Flag = True Then
           Lbl.Text = " "
            Lbl.Location = TxtName.Location + New Point(175, 0)
            'GrpBxDataInput.Controls.Remove(Lbl)
            'Lbl.Dispose()
            Flag = False!

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't create the label dynamically. Place it where it should appear, keep the text and switch it (in)visible when needed. That's much easier.

Comment: But what can I use instead of label? Also see http://prntscr.com/6alis2

Comment: A label is fine! But instead of creating it inside that function (`Dim Lbl As New Label`) you should create it in the WPF/Winforms designer like the textboxes and other controls. You could then modify the text or the visible-property inside that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right, your problem is, that you create a new label every time the keypress-function is called. You end up with a bunch of label over each other.
I suggest you do it like I mentioned in my comment on your question: create one label in the designer and switch it (in)visible:

```
Public Class Form1

...
// part of the designer block:
GrpBxDataInput.Controls.Add(MyWarningLabel)

  Private Sub TxtName_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtName.KeyPress
    Dim Txt As Integer = Asc(e.KeyChar)

    If (Txt < 65 Or Txt > 90) And (Txt < 97 Or Txt > 122) And Txt <> 8 And Txt <> 32 Then
      e.Handled = True
      MyWarningLabel.Text = "*Only Alphabets, Space and" & vbNewLine & "Backspace are allowed."
      MyWarningLabel.Visible = True
    Else
      MyWarningLabel.Text = ""
      MyWarningLabel.Visible = false
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding new label in vb[design] it is possible to visible it manually from code. Here is the solution:

```
Dim Flag As Boolean = False
Private Sub TxtName_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtName.KeyPress
    Dim Txt As Integer = Asc(e.KeyChar)

    If (Txt < 65 Or Txt > 90) And (Txt < 97 Or Txt > 122) And Txt <> 8 And Txt <> 32 Then
        e.Handled = True
        Lbl.Text = "*Only Alphabets, Space and" & vbNewLine & "Backspace are allowed."
        Lbl.AutoSize = True
        Lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Lbl.Visible = True
        Flag = True

    ElseIf Flag = True Then
        Lbl.Visible = False
        Flag = False

    End If
End Sub
```